# Android - reading google calendar events DOES NOT WORK anymore (there seems to be some kind of cache which does not return proper/fresh data)

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I have a simple app which reads google calendar events and displays them in list. It works flawlessly on all android version - except 10. Minimalistic example of code:

```
Uri.Builder builder = Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(builder, timeFrom);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, timeTo);

String projection = new String[] { Instances.EVENT_ID, Instances.TITLE };
String selection = null;
String args = null;
String sort = null;
cursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(), projection, selection, args, sort);
```

As I said - works perfectly, except android 10.

On android 10 I noticed interesting anomaly - whenever I make a change in official Google Calendar app, my app does not reflect changes immediately - it takes a while.

Its **completely random**, sometimes changes are immediate or take seconds to show, but often its minutes and sometimes even hours - but if I go to Google Calendar app and manually press refresh there, it helps (again its random - 90% times it works, but occasionaly it doesnt)>

I am almost 100% sure Google changed something in their API on android 10 - some kind of cache - so it behaves randomly and unreliable now. All calendar widgets I tried have same problem, so probably its not the fault of an app )besides, the code was pretty much copied from official webpage).

How to solve this problem? Why on android 10 changes are not immediate? *Is there a way to programatically trigger syncing/refresh of Google calendar from within my app?*

Comment: "its literally 10 lines of code copied from google website" -- it should be fairly easy for you to provide a [mcve] then! "they implemented some kind of annoying cache" -- there is nothing requiring Google Calendar to make its data available in any particular timeframe. Perhaps they are not exposing changes via `CalendarContract` until after they have synced with their server, for example. The implementation of Google Calendar is up to its developers.

Comment: I added piece of code. Yeah as you say, probably something changed in Google Calendar. However this creates a lot of problems for many people. I have busy schedule and add/edit/remove events during the day a lot - and I have never fresh data visible in my calendar widget. Unless I manually force synchronization after each change...And all other apps behave same, so there is no workaround. Really terrible implementation.